# how to get the values between a range in python

Tags: python

HI I wonder if you can help me with this

I want to print the values between 1 and 2 starting from 1 and add x to it until the value reaches 2.

I try to do it but it only prints 1.0625

```
x = 1/16

for i in range(1,2):
      b = i + x
      print(b)
```

I want it to print

```
1.0625
1.125
1.1875
1.25
1.3125
1.375
1.4375
1.5
1.5625
1.625
1.625
1.75
1.8125
1.875
1.9375
```

Thank you very much

Comment: There are infinite many of them; is it OK if it takes forever? If not, you have to put on constraints.

Comment: you need to compute how many step you need in advance - if you need n step, then loop over range(n)

Comment: `range(1, 2)` contains only one item: `1`, so your iteration runs only once. Please see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) for how `range()` works. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to add the steps between 1 and 2 seperately, the third argument of the range function lets you the the step size, here 1/16.

The steps between 1 and 2 are not integers, they are float numbers. Unfortunately Pythons `.range()` is unable to handle that natively. One option is to use numpys arange() which can handle float steps.

To print each value of a list you can use a `*` in front of the list. This tells the print command that it shall print each value in the list instead of the whole list.

since you want a new line for each value you can also set the seperator parameter of the print function: `sep="\n"`. This means each line is seperated by "\n" which is a linebreak in python console.

```
import numpy as np
print(*np.arange(1, 2, 1/16), sep="\n")
```

output:

```
1.0
1.0625
1.125
1.1875
1.25
1.3125
1.375
1.4375
1.5
1.5625
1.625
1.6875
1.75
1.8125
1.875
1.9375
```

Comment: This isn't the output the OP requires.

Comment: adjusted the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code as:

```
for i in range(1, 2):
    print(i)
```

then you will see that it only loops once and prints `1`.  As you can see in the documentation for [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) sequence types, it only deals with integers.

Rather than using a `for` loop over a range, you may want to use a `while` loop:

```
x = 1 / 16

i = 1
while i < 2 - x:
    i += x
    print(i)

# Output:
1.0625
1.125
1.1875
1.25
1.3125
1.375
1.4375
1.5
1.5625
1.625
1.6875
1.75
1.8125
1.875
1.9375
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use  `np.arrange`:

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(1,2,x)
```

**Output**

```
array([1.    , 1.0625, 1.125 , 1.1875, 1.25  , 1.3125, 1.375 , 1.4375,
       1.5   , 1.5625, 1.625 , 1.6875, 1.75  , 1.8125, 1.875 , 1.9375])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's arange function as already suggested, or you can use a while loop like in the example below.
The problem with python's range funtions is that it only accepts integers as arguments.

```
x = 1/16 
    
import numpy as np      
for i in np.arange(1,2,x):
    print(i)
    
  
value = 1.0
while value < 2:
    print(value)
    value = value + x
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `range` doesn't work well here because ranges work with integers, and you want to work with fractions.  You could coerce it by mapping your fractional range to an integer range via multiplication and division, but that seems unnecessarily complex to me.

Just taking your statement:

> starting from 1 and add x to it until the value reaches 2.

and phrasing it literally as code, we have a very simple approach:

```
b = 1
while b < 2:
    b += x
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment `i` in each loop iteration, instead of redeclaring the `i` value.

```py
x = 1/16
i = 1 + x
while i < 2:
    print(i)
    i += x
```